# How to extend sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice into a tabbed widget

Tags: php, forms, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a Doctrine form in Symfony 1.4.

**What I need to do:**

I need to show the same choices I am currently offering with a sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice object, but I would like to present them in a tabbed view.

My current view looks like:

```
[ ] option1
[ ] option2
[ ] option1.1
[ ] option1.2
[ ] option1.3
[ ] option2.1
[ ] option2.2
[ ] option2.3
[ ] option2.4
```

And I would like to show them like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| > option1 < |   option2   |   (tabs, option1 is the currently selected one)
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
 [ ] option1.1      (options on first tab)
 [ ] option1.2
 [ ] option1.3
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Options are related using a `parent` attribute.
The ones at the top row won't be checkable and their `parent` would be `NULL`.
I think I would manage to work that part out myself if I knew how to extend the class, I mean, which methods to redefine.

**What I've been trying:**

This is the widget's class inheritance:

*sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice*  <  *sfWidgetFormChoice* < *sfWidgetFormChoiceBase* < *sfWidgetForm* < *sfWidget*

And this is the form's class inheritance:

*ProductForm* < *BaseProductForm* < *BaseFormDoctrine* < *sfFormDoctrine* <  *sfFormObject*

And this is how the widget gets printed on the view:

```
<?php echo $form['product_type_list'] ?>
```

The thing is, with that last line I thought that I would find some magic __get() method on the form classes and (probably) a __toString() method on the widget classes, but I found none of them, and I'm still not sure about how to extend a widget in Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two possibilities to solve that problem:

The first is to write your own widget which inherits from `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`. So you can implement a custom `__toString()` method with your requirements. (See [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfFormField#method___tostring))

You should have a look at `sfWidgetFormChoice` and the target method self `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`. If you write you own class inherits from `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` you can overwrite the method `render` and `getJavaScripts`. In addition you can implements your own renderer for this widget, which make the js tabs and gui stuff.

The second option is, that you hide the default form field and build a new represention with javascript. You want to build tabs, so you should already use js to enable this?!

Comment: I've done before as your second suggestion says, but this time I wanted to do it the right, reusable way.  
I still don't get how to extend the widgets.  The doc page you pointed at is for "sfFormFieldSchema" wich is yet another class tree, and I wasn't aware of it's existence.  :-S

Comment: Well, that's right! You should have a look at `sfWidgetFormChoice` and the target method self `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`. If you write you own class inherits from `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` you can overwrite the method `render` and `getJavaScripts`. In addition you can implements your own renderer for this widget, which make the js tabs and gui stuff.

Comment: I just copied that last (very informative) comment into the answer itself in order to accept it as a whole.  Thank you!